# How to play Left 4 Dead 2 in split screen with two controllers?

Tags: games, screen, steam, gamepad

I would like to know if anybody managed to play **L4D2** in **split screen** under Ubuntu/Linux with **2 controllers** and how it was achieved.

I tried using different guides like [this one](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=316018167); split screen works, first player is controlled by controller 1 but nothing ever controls player 2.

I successfully used the `xboxdrv` driver to manage 8 wireless Xbox 360 controllers (with some scripts). Controllers work fine on games like Knight Squad, ClusterPuck 99, Portal 2 (Source game + 2 controllers), Screen Cheat, etc.

I successfully launch Left 4 Dead 2 in split screen with [this addon](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=278735311&searchtext=split%20screen). But nothing controls the second player.

I tried the different proposed solutions concerning the modification of the `360controller.cfg` file, but nothing changed.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I confirm the issue with Ubuntu. I fixed it by buying 2 Steam Controllers it works out of the box as left for dead 2 supports the Controllers. Tested with Ubuntu 14.04!